# Asp.Net Framework 4.6 MVC communicating with SignalR hosted on .Net Core WebApi

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, architecture, signalr, asp.net-core-2.0

I've got an **Asp.Net MVC WebApp** for which I want to establish a connection with the **SignalR Core** Hubs hosted on a **.NetCore 2.2 WebAPI** project.

Is that possible at all and if yes, which SignalR JavaScript client library should be used on the WebApp end?

The .NetCore WebAPI project has configured JWT Token authentication (as it is suggested in the MSDN documentation). I'm also searching for a way to pass the access_token along with the hub calls.

I've read all the articles in MSDN about configuring SignalR and Clients for .NetCore 2.x and the old Net 4.7 versions but never met an article properly explaining how to connect an old app with SignalR hosted on the new platform.

Thanks in advance to anyone taking the time to help me end this struggle!

Answer (score 0):

Ok, finally I've got it. 
Initially, I was trying to add **Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Client** library to my **Asp.Net Framework 4.6 WebApp** and it was rejecting the package with the message:

"You are trying to install this package into a project that targets '.NETFramework,Version=v4.6', but the package does not contain any assembly references or content files that are compatible with that framework."

Then after hours of research, I found this article: (https://github.com/aspnet/SignalR/issues/1645) saying that it was possible.

So I upgraded the .Net Framework version of the **WebApp** project from **4.6** to **4.7.1** and it worked!